# how to use Inheritance with the help of design patterns

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public interface Animal{
    public fight(Animal a){
    }  
}

//this interface is not accessible but exists somewhere in some other package and we are unaware about its exact location 
public class Tiger implements Animal{
    public fight(Animal a){
    } 
} 

//this interface is not accessible but exists somewhere in some other package and we are unaware about its exact location
public class Lion implements Animal{
    public fight(Animal a){
    }
} 

public testClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Animal a = factoryMethodToReturnTigerObject();//because we don't know how to create object directly.
        Animal b = factoryMethodToReturnLionObject();
    }
}
```

How will I generalize the implementation of fight to make it for any animal inside tiger?
As  `a.fight(animal)` accept not only dog type but also of type Animal.
Without using `instanceOf dog` and `instanceOf lion` how will I make sure it will perform for anything of animal.

The question is unrealistic (was actually asked me in one of the interviews) as you wont pass type cat (Say we have one more interface) to type dog.

But what if we do:
`a.fight(b);` and want it to work correctly.

Interviewer gave an hint that this is in regards with design patterns.
I am really not sure if this makes the constructive question.

Comment: Your `Lion` should be a class, not an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the guy interviewing you meant by hinting that this has to do with design patterns.  If I understand the question correctly, *it doesn't have to do with design patterns.*  Also, **your code is already doing what you want it to**:  Anything that implements animal will be able to fight any other type of thing that implements Animal.  That's what you wanted, right?  You're already there.  All you have to do is make some corrections to make it compile (the fight method needs a return type, like void).

Because the `fight` method in `Animal` takes another `Animal` as a parameter, so will everything that extends `Animal` (`Cat`, `Dog`, `Duck`, `Goose`, `Lion`, `Tiger`, `Bear`, Oh My!) -- the way you have it written, it already meets your goal.  The fight method doesn't care about what kind of `Animal` it is, as long as it is an `Animal`.

```
public interface Animal {
    void fight(Animal otherAnimal);
}

public class Tiger implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void fight(Animal otherAnimal) {
        //Do Stuff
    } 
} 

public class Lion implements Animal {
    @Override
    public fight(Animal otherAnimal) {
       //Do Stuff
    }
} 

public class Dog implements Animal {
    @Override
    public fight(Animal otherAnimal) {
       //Do Stuff
    }
} 

public class TestClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Animal a = factoryMethodToReturnTigerObject();
        Animal b = factoryMethodToReturnLionObject();
        a.fight(b); // This works
        b.fight(a); // This also works

        Dog dog = factoryMethodToReturnDogObject();
        Tiger tiger = factoryMethodToReturnTigerObject();
        dog.fight(tiger); // This works.
        tiger.fight(dog); // This also works.  You're good to go!

    }
}
```

In fact, if you **wanted it the other way around** so that animals could only fight other animals of the same type, you would have to go out of your way, and use generics like this:

Animal:

```
public interface Animal<A extends Animal<A>> {
    void fight(A otherAnimal);
}
```

Tiger:

```
public class Tiger implements Animal<Tiger>{
    @Override
    public void fight(Tiger otherAnimal) {
        //Do Stuff
    } 
}
```

Lion:

```
public class Lion implements Animal<Lion> {
    @Override
    public void fight(Lion otherLion) {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: How does `public interface Animal<A extends Animal<A>>`  line works ? Can you please elaborate? Appreciate your help.

Comment: It sets up `A` as a generic parameter that represents anything that extends Animal.  Then, when you set up your `Tiger` class, you set it to extend `Animal` with its generic type set to `Tiger` (which works because it extends Animal).  Then, the fight method of `Tiger` will *only* accept another `Tiger` as a parameter -- which, I believe, is the opposite of what you want.  My point is that you already have what you want and it's actually *more* complicated to do the opposite.

Comment: The description that you gave really added to my knowledge base. But I think the interviewer was expecting handle even those cases where you can pass dog to tiger. If it is a case how can we handle that ?

Comment: I elaborated my answer a bit to help.  Basically my point is that your code is already accomplishing what the interviewer wants.

Answer (score 1):

The design pattern that this is an example of is **Programming to an Interface**. This allows you to separate your code out into different layers, and the consumer of those interfaces doesn't need to have any knowledge about how anything is actually implemented (because it shouldn't care). The big thing that this philosophy opens up is **Dependency Injection**.

The code that you're writing will have knowledge of an interface. Then you could have a completely different project that contains the concrete implementation of those interfaces. It doesn't matter where they are or what they do. All your code would need to know is that whatever the object is, knows how to do what you need to with it.

In your example, you wouldn't have it set up like the `Main` you have there. It'd be something more like this:

```
public class RumbleInTheJungle {
    public Animal Match(Animal animal1, Animal animal2) {
        animal1.fight(animal2);
    }
}

public testClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Tiger tiger = new Tiger();
        Lion lion = new Lion();
        RumbleInTheJungle jungle = new RumbleInTheJungle();

        Animal winner = jungle.Match(tiger, lion);
    }
}
```

This is a highly simplified example, but should hopefully help you understand a little more. I don't have any Dependency Injection set up as I'm not sure how it's done in Java, but that isn't directly necessary to understand the pattern.

Comment: I think you understood what the interviewer was getting at a bit better than I did.  Probably what got me is that I've never thought of **Programming to an Interface** as a design pattern, but rather principle. 
That aside, **Dependency Injection** wouldn't apply here, unless you made `Match` an object that has two animals.  Then you could make a constructor where you pass in two `Animal`s.

Comment: Agreed. I was hesitant about calling it a design pattern, but didn't want to get too far away from what the OP was understanding. As I said at the end, this example wasn't the best for Dependency Injection without getting far too complex with it, and I only brought it up as one of the best reasons to adapt the principle.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
public interface Animal {
    public <T extends Animal> fight(T a);
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? How will you handle even those cases where you can pass dog to tiger ? It should handle all types of animals even if it is class of dog which is meant to handle dogs. But imagine someone passes lion to dog and we dont use generics.